# Updating params with a value from a form within a modal

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I have been searching for an answer to this online, but because I'm new to rails none of the answers have been easy enough for me to understand.

I have a few forms within a modal popup that I'd like to get information from into a controller.  I'm using Foundation to create the form, and the html is as follows:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
          <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
          <input name="input1" type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Full name here">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

I would like to get the value from `input1` into a controller to play around with or add to my database, and I was wondering if anyone could give a good explanation for the best way to go about this, or provide a link to a good explanation as to how I do this.  Is it good practice to add these values to my `params` and then access it from the controller?  That was what I initially thought would be a good idea, but I can't even seem to figure that out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine Rails with Foundation, you need to modify it like the following:

```
<%= form_for @name_of_object_declared_in_your_controller_for_this_action do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
          <%= f.label :input1 %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
          <%= f.text_field :input1, placeholder: 'Full name here' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For more information about implementing forms in Rails, I would suggest reading the Rails Guide for [Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Comment: Gotcha.  So is it generally a bad idea to try and put these values into `params` and access them from there?

Comment: When you submit the form, the value for `:input1` will be available in the params hash and you'll be able to access it via `params[:input1]`.

Comment: And how do I name the method in my controller that would use this object?  Do I need to add another line to the HTML?

Comment: I would suggest reading the [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) Rails Guide since it will answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: Also, Code School has a pretty awesome free course called [Rails for Zombies Redux](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux) that contains great videos and course materials that should give you a pretty good basic understanding of the Rails framework.